# PSEXEC without terminate batch job

Tags: windows, windows-services, psexec

I'm trying to make my windows service run bat file with

> psexec  -accepteula -h -i 1 myapp.exe --p1 lala --p2 lalala

but closing the myapp cmd window results with "Terminate batch job y/n" question and service doesn't get the fact that it needs to restart itself.
In order to ignore this question, I googled and tried add

> < nul

to the end of the command, but that didn't help. I assume that psexec doesn't get the fact, that "< nul" part is not for myapp but for psexec itself. 
So how can I make my psexec finish without any questions about terminating batch job?

Comment: Ideally, you'd fix the problem in `myapp.exe`, but I'm guessing this is a third-party executable, perhaps generated by a batch-to-exe converter?  You could probably use something like `psexec [...] cmd /c "myapp.exe [...] < nul"`

Comment: I don`t get your original idea. If you need to run exe file as a service on LOCAL system, why are you creating bat. file and trying to use psexec?

Comment: Because I need to run exe in my session with UI (and I do psexec -i 1for it)

Comment: Harry, I can't do cmd /c because in this case something could close the cmd window and service will decide to restart itself, but window with myapp.exe will remain working

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a SECOND batch file. The second file will call the first batch file and it will append "< nul".

For example, say you had a batch file which contained the following line:

```
    python manage.py runserver
```

Name this file something like **file1.bat**

Then create a second batch file which contains the line:

```
    file1.bat < nul
```

Name the second file something like **file2.bat**   Then, execute the second file from that point on in order to call your program.

This worked for me in a Windows 10 environment.  Good luck.